# Token based remember me cookie is not working at the time of autologin redirection

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, remember-me

I am using spring security 4.1.1 and spring boot for authentication its working totally good. Now I started to implement remember me below is my configuration code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;
    // UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login", "/signup","/logout", "/loginProcess","/public/**","/forgotpassword","/forgot-password*","/isUserExists","/emailForgot","/verify-user*").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()

    .rememberMe().key("tokenkey").rememberMeParameter("_spring_security_remember_me").rememberMeCookieName("myremembermecookie").tokenValiditySeconds(1209600).alwaysRemember(true).userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .and()


                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/loginProcess").defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                .failureUrl("/login?error").usernameParameter("userName").passwordParameter("userPassword").permitAll()
                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true).permitAll().and().headers().defaultsDisabled().cacheControl();

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }


}
```

This is my custom authentication provider code

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{

     public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationProvider.class);

    @Autowired
    WyzbeeGatewayService sdkService;

    @Autowired
    UserData userData;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        logger.info("###############################################################################################");
        logger.info(authentication.getName()+" "+authentication.getCredentials());
        logger.info("###############################################################################################");
         try {
                final String userToken = sdkService.login(authentication.getName(), authentication.getCredentials().toString());
                final LoginResponse responseValidate = sdkService.validateUser(authentication.getName(), authentication.getCredentials().toString());
                userData.setUserTenantList(responseValidate.getUserTenantList());
                List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
                userData.setUserName(authentication.getName());
                userData.setPasswrod(authentication.getCredentials().toString());
                userData.setGrantedAuths(grantedAuths);
                userData.setUserToken(userToken);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authentication.getName(), authentication.getCredentials().toString(), grantedAuths);
               logger.info("checking for authentication "+usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.isAuthenticated()); 
             //UserDetails user = new User(authentication.getName(), authentication.getCredentials().toString(), true, true, true, true, grantedAuths);
               //SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new RememberMeAuthenticationToken("tokenkey", authentication.getName(), grantedAuths));
             /*  UserService userService = new UserService();
               userService.setUserDetails(user);*/
               return usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
            } catch (final WyzbeeException e) {
                 throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username " + authentication.getName() + " not found");
            }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {

        return true;
    }
```

As I don't have direct access to the database we have a rest call for login and logout so I was not able to use directly `UserDetailsService`I used `AuthenticationProvider` to check the credentials but, spring document says if you want to use in-built remember me mechanisms we should have `UserDetailsService` so I implemented in this way

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    UserDetails user= null;

    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserService.class);

    @Autowired
    WyzbeeGatewayService sdkService;

    @Autowired
    UserData userData;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        /*logger.info("###############################################################################################");
        logger.info("User Service "+userData.getUserName());
        logger.info("###############################################################################################");*/
        return new User(userData.getUserName(), userData.getPasswrod(), true, true, true, true, userData.getGrantedAuths());
    }

    public void setUserDetails(UserDetails user){
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

The problem is the cookie is generating and storing in browser when I login for first time after login I am closing the browser without  logout when I again access my URL it is again moving to login page.  I dent mention anything in index.jsp just maintained to redirect to login page.

Debugged content

```
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:157 - Checking match of request : '/public/css/style.css'; against '/'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:157 - Checking match of request : '/public/css/style.css'; against '/login'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:157 - Checking match of request : '/public/css/style.css'; against '/signup'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1044 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:157 - Checking match of request : '/public/css/style.css'; against '/logout'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1000 - Successfully completed request
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:157 - Checking match of request : '/public/css/style.css'; against '/loginProcess'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:117 - Chain processed normally
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:157 - Checking match of request : '/public/css/style.css'; against '/public/**'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:119 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:219 - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /public/css/style.css; Attributes: [permitAll]
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG OrderedRequestContextFilter:104 - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4954e173
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:348 - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@7a88a3ec: Principal: swapnil1472; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@380f4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 3B315D5D7EF75385D93713710B62079C; Not granted any authorities
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG AffirmativeBased:66 - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@5de2ed51, returned: 1
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:243 - Authorization successful
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:256 - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:310 - /public/css/style.css reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:865 - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/virtual/public/css/style.css]
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:190 - Matching patterns for request [/public/css/style.css] are [/public/**, /**]
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:219 - URI Template variables for request [/public/css/style.css] are {}
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:140 - Mapping [/public/css/style.css] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [static/public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@1c026d4e]]] and 1 interceptor
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:951 - Last-Modified value for [/virtual/public/css/style.css] is: -1
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1044 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1000 - Successfully completed request
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:117 - Chain processed normally
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:119 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG OrderedRequestContextFilter:104 - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@634ebe6
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG OrderedRequestContextFilter:114 - Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@634ebe6
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG OrderedRequestContextFilter:114 - Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4954e173
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 - /public/css/fonts/eau_sans_book-webfont.woff at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 - /public/css/fonts/eau_sans_bold-webfont.woff at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 - /public/css/fonts/eau_sans_book-webfont.woff at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 - /public/css/fonts/eau_sans_bold-webfont.woff at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:207 - Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@7a88a3ec: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@7a88a3ec: Principal: swapnil1472; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@380f4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 3B315D5D7EF75385D93713710B62079C; Not granted any authorities'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:207 - Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@7a88a3ec: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@7a88a3ec: Principal: swapnil1472; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@380f4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 3B315D5D7EF75385D93713710B62079C; Not granted any authorities'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 - /public/css/fonts/eau_sans_book-webfont.woff at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 - /public/css/fonts/eau_sans_bold-webfont.woff at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 - /public/css/fonts/eau_sans_book-webfont.woff at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 - /public/css/fonts/eau_sans_bold-webfont.woff at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG OrRequestMatcher:65 - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG OrRequestMatcher:65 - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:157 - Checking match of request : '/public/css/fonts/eau_sans_bold-webfont.woff'; against '/logout'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG OrRequestMatcher:65 - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:137 - Request 'GET /public/css/fonts/eau_sans_bold-webfont.woff' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG OrRequestMatcher:65 - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:137 - Request 'GET /public/css/fonts/eau_sans_bold-webfont.woff' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG OrRequestMatcher:65 - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:137 - Request 'GET /public/css/fonts/eau_sans_bold-webfont.woff' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG OrRequestMatcher:72 - No matches found
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:157 - Checking match of request : '/public/css/fonts/eau_sans_book-webfont.woff'; against '/logout'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 - /public/css/fonts/eau_sans_bold-webfont.woff at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:137 - Request 'GET /public/css/fonts/eau_sans_bold-webfont.woff' doesn't match 'POST /loginProcess
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG OrRequestMatcher:65 - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:137 - Request 'GET /public/css/fonts/eau_sans_book-webfont.woff' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG OrRequestMatcher:65 - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:137 - Request 'GET /public/css/fonts/eau_sans_book-webfont.woff' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG OrRequestMatcher:65 - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:137 - Request 'GET /public/css/fonts/eau_sans_book-webfont.woff' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG OrRequestMatcher:72 - No matches found
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 - /public/css/fonts/eau_sans_bold-webfont.woff at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 - /public/css/fonts/eau_sans_book-webfont.woff at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:137 - Request 'GET /public/css/fonts/eau_sans_book-webfont.woff' doesn't match 'POST /loginProcess
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 - /public/css/fonts/eau_sans_bold-webfont.woff at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 - /public/css/fonts/eau_sans_book-webfont.woff at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 - /public/css/fonts/eau_sans_book-webfont.woff at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 - /public/css/fonts/eau_sans_bold-webfont.woff at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 - /public/css/fonts/eau_sans_book-webfont.woff at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG RememberMeAuthenticationFilter:154 - SecurityContextHolder not populated with remember-me token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@7a88a3ec: Principal: swapnil1472; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@380f4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 3B315D5D7EF75385D93713710B62079C; Not granted any authorities'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG RememberMeAuthenticationFilter:154 - SecurityContextHolder not populated with remember-me token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@7a88a3ec: Principal: swapnil1472; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@380f4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 3B315D5D7EF75385D93713710B62079C; Not granted any authorities'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 - /public/css/fonts/eau_sans_book-webfont.woff at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:325 - /public/css/fonts/eau_sans_bold-webfont.woff at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-09-27 11:51:24 DEBUG AnonymousAuthenticationFilter:106 - SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@7a88a3ec: Principal: swapnil1472; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@380f4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 3B315D5D7EF75385D93713710B62079C; Not granted any authorities'
```

Comment: What on earth is `UserData` and why should it be populated in your userservice if someone is using a remember me cookie?!

Comment: you are missing resource mapping...check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39698199/4117061)

Comment: `UserData` is the value object which contain user credentials (see CustomAuthenticationProvider) I am using this because I don't have any rest control which takes username and returns password as of to use `loadUserByUserName(String username)` so I used `AuthenticationProvider` for authentication and `UserDetailsService` for remember-me as a reference because `rememberme` requires `UserDetailsService`

Comment: So and what do you think happens... `UserData` is set by each authentication attempt, now imagine 100 individual authentications are made. What will the value of `UserData` be? Also if it a request or session scoped object it will not help you as when closing the browser and issueing a new request no session is there and you will get null pointers or non-existing users. Basically what you are trying is first off all dangerous and will simply not work.

Comment: Yes I got you and I have observed that `UserData` is your overriding with latest loged-in user. What is the solution for this?

Comment: I come up with an understanding I need to store an extra data whatever present in `UserData` should store in `SecurityContext` then I can perform multi-user login... Is this the correct way? @M. Deinum

Comment: No that won't work. Your solution and thinking is flawed. When someone uses a remember me cookie you need to obtain the user information again from the webservice. You simply cannot store it in some variable. Even if that would work, now scale it to 2 or 5 instances, what if he first hits server1, then later hits server3... What has happened to his data?